# Want to execute a perl script within a perl script

Tags: perl, process, exec, fork

I need a help on perl. I am new to it.
I want to execute a perl script from my parent perl script and cover the following scenarios:

```
if (my child script takes more time than my time limit)
{
    I need to kill the child script with a return code 
    logged into my parent script log file
}

if (my child script failed to execute)
{
     I need to write a new RC to my parent script logfile 
     by looking at my child script exit status
}
```

Can any body provide code for this like how to use fork, exec and process related commands
to fetch process id of children when my parent script gets executed?

Comment: Only a parent can kill a child. :D

Answer (score 1):

The [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) (inter-process communication) man page would be a good place to start.

Comment: perlipc is quite daunting for beginners. Unfortunately I don't have anything else to recommend.

Comment: forking is not really a beginner topic.  But it is pretty straight forward, and the perlipc page isn't really that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Generally:

fork() returns an in integer, undef if it fails.

You check the value of the integer

1. if it is 0 then you're in the child, and you run your childish tasks.
2. if it is not 0 then your in the parent, and you have the pid of the child, so you wait for it, or reap it as needed.

There's a good example of the skeleton of this kind of code in the perlipc document that davorg already mentioned.